# MongoDB on Windows 7 32 bit w/ NodeJS

Tags: mongodb, storage-engines

How can I change the storage engine of MongoDB permanantly so that I don't have to run mongod without having to specify the storage engine everytime? . I am using shell version 3.2.7 on Windows 7 32 bit. I got an error that said `28663 Cannot start server. The default storage engine 'wiredTiger' is not available with this build of mongod. Please specify a different storage engine explicitly, e.g. --storageEngine=mmapv1., terminating.`

Also does anyone know how to cleanly shutdown the server when I am done working, I use ctrl + c` but it causes an error then I have to empty the data folder to get the process to start again. Thanks

I asked this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com 7 hours ago but I haven't received any answers as yet so I've decided to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

You can set that in the [`storage.config`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.engine) setting within your YAML configuration file.

Example:

```
storage:
  dbPath: d:\data\db
  engine: mmapv1
```

If you're not already starting your MongoDB service using a configuration file, see [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/#configure-a-windows-service-for-mongodb-community-edition) for the details on how do to that for Windows.